# How attach a native thread to a running CLRhost?

Tags: .net, interop, clr

With JNI code I can attach a native thread to the JVM and execute whatever I want. How do I do the same on the .NET CLR? I can't find any such function here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404385.aspx

Comment: Since you can P/Invoke `CreateThread`, why would there need to be any other special support?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, my c# code is running and now I start a native program with a native thread that wants to call c# methods on the running c# vm.

Comment: [Heres an msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx#S3) discussing the hosting interfaces that are used to control the internal native thread creation use by the CLR when hosted, and how to provide a way to alter the defaults so that you can control them. Note that the documentation and the API calls threads 'Tasks' for the purpose of abstracting the concept away from the thread specifics in the api.

Comment: I don't see a function that allows me to attach a thread. How does C++/Cli do this anyway, they start a CLR in the background?

Comment: Pretty sure dark magic is involved. As far as actually actually attaching a thread - if you mean that the CLR code creates a new thread and you want to return your thread, thats [IHostTaskManager::CreateTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164565.aspx)

Comment: Actually relying on this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59(v=vs.110).aspx you can see that `When an unmanaged thread enters the runtime through, for example, a COM callable wrapper, the system checks...` so its possible to enter from bottom to top in managed space, and some magic happens to make it work so it seems.